# python selenium doesnot bypass firefox download dialog even though preferences have been set

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to download file (market Summary (Closing) — ZIP  ) from the following link:
https://dps.psx.com.pk/downloads

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import date
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.preferences.instantApply",True)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",0)


driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://dps.psx.com.pk/downloads')

start_date = driver.find_element_by_id('downloadsDatePicker')
start_date.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE*10)
send_date = date(2014,1,1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_date.send_keys(send_date)
driver.find_element_by_id('downloadsSearchBtn').click()
link = '/download/mkt_summary/{}.Z'.format(send_date)
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='{}'".format(link)).click()
```

Even though I have set the preferences, firefox still pops up a download dialog box. Why is it so and how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: I have also tried this: 'application/x-z', 'application/x-compress', 'application/z', but none of these seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the site and link you are preparing, you are not downloading csv file but mostly a zip file with .Z extension.

You need to change the code for preference `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` to allow the response received from the site as shown below.

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")
```